# Short story of a man missing his opportunity to escape his unhappy life on earth

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Read this story in an anthology of not strictly science fiction many years ago. A man unhappy with his life is offered the opportunity after an interview to escape this world and live in basically a paradise. The person/alien who is interviewing him lets him know several famous individuals from the past have gone there. Judge Crater and Ambrose Bierce I seem to recall. He passes the interview, goes to the proper location, is in a room with other people and then decides cynically it is all a scam and he is being played for a fool. He leaves the room just in time to miss out and once he realizes he blew it he tries to re-interview and is turned down. Back to his doldrum life. Any one remember this one?

Comment: Does [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6119/short-story-about-a-travel-agency-and-a-simple-life-paradise/6159#6159) answer your question?

Comment: Yes and thank you. This site is so amazing. I have not yet failed to have the answer delivered. Much appreciated. That story stuck with me.

Comment: If so, please accept the answer below.  We also may mark this as a duplicate -- no reflection on your question; it is bookkeeping of sorts...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Short Story About a "Travel Agency" And A "Simple Life" Paradise](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6119/short-story-about-a-travel-agency-and-a-simple-life-paradise) - You already confirmed this above, but this comment is automatically inserted when we suggest marking it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 12):

Maybe [Of Missing Persons](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Of_Missing_Persons) by Jack Finney?

> "Missing Persons" is a 1955 science fiction short story by American
> writer Jack Finney, which describes a burned-out bank teller named
> Charley Ewell living in 1955 New York City who receives a chance to
> emigrate from Earth to Verna, a lush, earthlike planet light-years
> away

And:

> Over time the Vernans opened branches of Acme Travel Bureau in every
> major city and invited people from all over the earth, including
> ***Ambrose Bierce*** and, speculates Charley, ***Judge Crater***.

And:

> As he sits and waits in the dark barn, Charley descends into a rage
> after he concludes he has been played for a fool. He storms out of the
> barn, but just as he crosses the threshold, he looks back and briefly
> glimpses, in a flash of light, the planet Verna through the back
> window of the barn before the barn door slams shut. By the time he
> gets the barn door back open, the people he left in the barn are gone,
> taken to Verna.

Google search: Short story Judge Crater and Ambrose Bierce

Comment: If so, it has been asked, and answered several times. [This example](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6119/short-story-about-a-travel-agency-and-a-simple-life-paradise/6159#6159) has an accepted answer.